# Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop on RAID-5 with LVM, GRUB failed to install

Tags: grub2, raid, lvm

I want to configure a home media center and file storage, to keep the data safe I want to use RAID-5 (I have 4 HDs) and LVM for future scaling.

I've configured RAID-5 and LVM, but GRUB installation failed.

I booted from live CD and activated the RAID, found the LVM volumes.

How can I install GRUB and where should it be? In the LVM or the raid volume md0 itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the problem.

I read that GRUB can be placed inside the LVM and that it is somehow possible, however with the lack of proper documentation I DO NOT recommend trying this. That is what caused the problem, placing GRUB inside LVM volume on RAIeD-5.

To fix this, all you need to do is write GRUB to the regular HD's, outside of the RAID partitions. You can do this be "chroot"ing, but I have found an easier way:

Boot from Live CD, and make sure you have internet connection, then:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install boot-repair -y
sudo boot-repair
```

This will launch a GUI repair tool, follow the instructions carefully and it will re-install GRUB for you.

The lesson is do not place GRUB in an LVM volume upon installation, choose one of the hard drives, outside the RAID partitions i.e. /sda, /sdb/, etc...

Good Luck.

Comment: Choose one? And what about the other ones?